# Text color is barely noticeable on Company page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The title for widgets on the stackoverflow company pages uses a link color which  is barely noticeable. At our company's page ([Wire](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/wire)) you can hardly see the "Who you'll work with" and "Locations". I made a screenshot to highlight it.

On my screenshot you can see the "Who you'll work with" (because I marked it with the mouse) but it's hard to read "Location" which is shown in the next widget.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

This was a bad CSS refactoring that has now been fixed.

Thanks for your report <3

Comment: Wow! Great! I am really impressed by your quick response. Bug read, confirmed, fixed and fix deployed in less than 45 minutes. This is how web development is done! :)

Comment: @Benny well, Careers is the main source of income for Stack Exchange so... :-)